# Cannot implicit convert type List to IEnumerable while grouping with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

New to MVC and Linq.

I'm was able to display all records just fine but now I was trying to get a count of records by name and just select 2 fields:Name and Count

I thought I should create a new ViewModel, fill the Name,Count and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var load =
            db.loadingPPHs.Where(s => s.WORKDAY == db.loadingPPHs.Max(x => x.WORKDAY))
                .GroupBy(fu => fu.TMNAME)
                .Select(g => new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}).ToList();


        var viewModel = new loadingViewModel
        {
            LoadingListCount = load
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The linq above works as expected. 
ViewModel:

```
public class loadingViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<LoadingListCount> LoadingListCount { get; set; }


    }

    public class LoadingListCount
    {

        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

    }
```

However, I'm getting an error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have trying converting the query to list and to IEnumerable but no luck. I've searched around other posts but I have not have luck with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because of two main things, first one is the Linq produces a collection of an anonymous type, and the attached `.ToList()` gives you the result as List of anonymous type objects. But the expected result would be of type `IEnumerable<LoadingListCount>` so here we need to do few changes, First of all, we have to create an object of type `LoadingListCount` now the Linq will give you the output as expected, But the attached `.ToList()` will convert them to `List<LoadingListCount>` to avoid that we have to remove them as well. Finally, the query will look like the following:

```
var load = db.loadingPPHs.Where(s => s.WORKDAY == db.loadingPPHs.Max(x => x.WORKDAY))
                         .GroupBy(fu => fu.TMNAME)
                         .Select(g => new LoadingListCount {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.Select(g => new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

produces objects of *anonymous* type, and puts them into a list. Since you need `IEnumerable<LoadingListCount>`, not `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>` create instances of `LoadingListCount` instead by specifying the type in the invocation of `new` operator:

```
.Select(g => new LoadingListCount {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is creating a collection of anonymous objects - you need to project your query into your model

```
IEnumerable<LoadingListCount> load = 
    db.loadingPPHs.Where(s => s.WORKDAY == db.loadingPPHs.Max(x => x.WORKDAY))
        .GroupBy(fu => fu.TMNAME)
        .Select(g => new LoadingListCount { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
var viewModel = new loadingViewModel
{
    LoadingListCount = load
};
```